# I2C on PIC microcontroller

Tags: pic, i2c

I am trying to to use I2C to communicate with a sensor. I have a 2.2k pull-up resistors to a 3.3V supply for my SDA/SCL. The microcontroller I am using is a PIC16F18324. In my tests I do not have the slave connected. Apparently, my SDA line is being pulled low by the microcontroller and I am unable to transmit any data through the lines.

Here are two references I have been using:
https://www.8051projects.net/wiki/I2C_Implementation_on_PIC
https://electrosome.com/i2c-pic-microcontroller-mplab-xc8/

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ  4000000 //4 Mhz

uint16_t count = 0;

void I2C_Master_Init(const unsigned long c)
{
    TRISC = 1; // Enable TrisC RC0-SCL/RC1-SDA

    SSP1STAT |= 0b10000000;
    SSP1CON1 = 0b00101000; //Configure for master mode
    SSP1CON2 = 0b00000000;
    SSPADD = (_XTAL_FREQ/(4*c))-1;
}

void I2C_Master_Wait()
{
  while ((SSP1STAT & 0b00000100) || (SSP1CON2 & 0x00011111)); //Check if busy
}

void I2C_Master_Start()
{
  //I2C_Master_Wait();    
  SEN = 1;             //Initiate start condition
  while(SEN);
}

void I2C_Master_RepeatedStart()
{
  //I2C_Master_Wait();
  RSEN = 1;           //Initiate repeated start condition
  while(RSEN);
}

void I2C_Master_Stop()
{
  //I2C_Master_Wait();
  PEN = 1;           //Initiate stop condition
  while(PEN);
}

void I2C_Master_Write(unsigned data)
{

  SSP1BUF = data;         //Write data to SSP1BUF
  while(BF);
  I2C_Master_Wait();
}

unsigned short I2C_Master_Read(unsigned short a)
{
  unsigned short temp;
  RCEN = 1;
  while(!BF);
  temp = SSP1BUF;      //Read data from SSP1BUF
  I2C_Master_Wait();
  ACKDT = (a)?0:1;    //Acknowledge bit
  ACKEN = 1;          //Acknowledge sequence
  return temp;
}

void main(void)
{     
    OSCCON1 = 0x60; // HFINTOSC   Higher, faster
    OSCFRQ = 0x03;  // HFFRQ 4_MHz; Enables 4Mhz for Register HFINTOSC

    I2C_Master_Init(100000); //Initialize I2C Master w/ 100Khz Clock

    while (1)
    {
        I2C_Master_Start();         //Start condition
        I2C_Master_Write(0x05);     //7 bit address + Write
        I2C_Master_Write(0xFF);     //Write data
        I2C_Master_Stop();          //Stop condition
        __delay_ms(200);

    }
}
```

Comment: `TRISC = 1` only sets RC0 as a tri-stated input. Try changing that to `TRISC = 0b11` instead.

Comment: Ah whoops I messed that up. That actually fixed my pull down problem. However, I still cannot see any being transmitted on the line.

Answer (score 1):

I2C_Master_Write(0x05);     //7 bit address + Write

Check this line , instead of  writing the value you are reading the value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the line `ACKDT = (a)?0:1;`. Try `ACKDT = 1;` instead.

```
/*********************************************************************/
void I2C_Master_Wait(void)
    {
   while ((SSPSTAT & 0x04) || (SSPCON2 & 0x1F));
    }
/*********************************************************************/
void I2C_Master_Start(void)
    {
    I2C_Master_Wait();
    SEN = 1;
    }
/*******************************************************************/
void I2C_Master_Stop(void)
    {
    I2C_Master_Wait();
    PEN = 1;
    }
/******************************************************************/
unsigned unint8 I2C_Master_Read(unsigned short a)
   {
   unsigned unint8 temp;
   I2C_Master_Wait();
   RCEN = 1;
   I2C_Master_Wait();
   temp = SSPBUF;
   I2C_Master_Wait();
   //ACKDT = (a)?0:1; //This occurs problem
   ACKDT = 1;  //SHOULD TRY THIS
   ACKEN = 1;
   return temp;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another problem:

```
TRISC = 1; // Enable TrisC RC0-SCL/RC1-SDA
```

Only RC0 is an input.
 Try this:

```
TRISC = 0x03; // Enable TrisC RC0-SCL/RC1-SDA
```

And please remember to switch the port to digital:

```
ANSELC = 0x00; // Enable TrisC RC0-SCL/RC1-SDA
```